# Fail to deploy a web application project using TOMCAT(I'm using xampp for that)

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, project

Undeploying ...
OK - Undeployed application at context path [/bankingSystem]
In-place deployment at C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\bankingSystem\build\web
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fadity%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext215087617306647603.xml&path=/bankingSystem
FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/bankingSystem] but context failed to start
C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\bankingSystem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1030: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

I want to just run my web application according to my .xml file

Comment: Did you check the server log?

Comment: yes i did. Actually I reinstall the xampp, but still got the same error.